# How to get data making http request only first time?

Tags: angular

I have a angular 2 service.
Now I have to get some objects from the server only if they don't exist already.

So for first time I want to make a http request and then store the data in a variable defined in the service. For subsequent requests, I just pass the data from the variable.

What will be the ideal way to do it in `angular 2 style` with `Observables`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap your http request into an injectable service and use the side effect operator do(), for example,

```
@Injectable()
export class DataService{

    mydata: Array[];

    constructor(private http:Http){}

    loadData(): Observable | any {
        if (this.mydata){
            return this.mydata;  // return from cache
        } else
        {
            return this.http.get("./mydata.json")
                .map(res => res.json())
                .do(data => this.mydata = data);
        }
    }
}
```

Invoke the loadData() from your component. It'll make an http request only if mydata is null.

Comment: But with this approach, the return types are different. In that case how will My calling function decides whether it subscribe to the observable or it will get array ?

Comment: You can turn an array into Observable if you wish: 

return Observable.from(this.mydata)

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
observable.first().subscribe(yourFunc);
```

This will only call the subscribe function once.